# Adding user created snippets between template strings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Below I created a snippet that I was going to use in a styled component. The snippet responds to the listed prefix as expected as long as I do not use the snippet inside of a styled component. My question is if there is something that I need to include in the body of my snippet to be able to use the snippet regardless of if it is between template tags or not?

User Created Snippet:

```
{
    "React Theme": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript,jsx",
        "prefix": "theme",
        "body": [
            "${props => props.theme.${1:element}}",
        ],
        "description": "React theme"
    }
}
```

Short Clip of [Behavior in editor](https://share.getcloudapp.com/RBuvXNYg)

Answer (score 3):

It may be because your `scope` language mode should be `javascriptreact` instead of `jsx`:

```
"scope": "javascript,typescript,javascriptreact",
```

Click on the file's language in the lower right corner and you will open a panel with all supported language modes with the proper spelling usage in parentheses - like `Javascript React (javascriptreact)` use that part in parentheses in settings or snippets that require a language mode.

Also put this into your settings:

```
 "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true         // this is the important one for you!!
  },
```

so snippets get triggered in a template string.

Try using a different prefix than `theme`, does that conflict with something in an extension?

Works fine for me:

[image: theme snippet]

Comment: So that didn't work, but I think I found the actual problem. In a new file I use template string and the snippet works when the template string is on one line. When I split the template string over multiple lines, the snippet is ignored. https://share.getcloudapp.com/7Ku0yqoL

Comment: So I am wondering if this a font-related issue because the behavior of auto-completion of 2 template strings is not engaged when I type one that is touching a string.

Comment: Yeah, because your behavior on having a word next to the template string is the same so that rules that out.

Comment: I see you have two `theme` snippets - one in the global snippets file and on in users.  Shouldn't be a problem but I would try renaming the one you want to use.  If you type `theme` and "Ctrl+Space" does it bring up the snippet suggestion?

Comment: When I removed the other snippet along with the removal of more plugins than I want to admit to having, it's working. I think that the lesson to be learned here is, you probably don't need 400+ VS Code plugins. Thanks for your help

Comment: I added an edit above which might be important - about the `quickSuggestions` setting.

Comment: Thanks for that!!